# R dataframe: how to slice data based column value of distinct values in another column

Tags: r

I am wondering how would I select unique values in one column based on the maximum value in another column for each original distinct value.

Original data frame:

```
a   b   

A   3
B   4
C   5
C   8
A   11
```

Expected data frame:

```
a   b   

A   11
B   4
C   8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a a group by `max`

```
aggregate(b ~ a, df1, max)
```

---

If we have multiple columns in the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(a) %>%
   slice(which.max(b))
```